# What happens when I double click an executable, technically

Tags: c++, windows, go, createprocess

*tl;dr*

I'm trying to understand the difference of running a program directly via double clicking the executable vs running it through a terminal or programatically via `CreateProcess` in windows 10.

---

*long version*

Because this is my problem, executing an old game (circa 2003 using D3D8) through double clicking in windows 10 works okay. Executing the game through an seconday executable (also circa 2003) using `CreateProcess` seems to sometimes work okay.

But executing it through my new golang executable never works. I get a very tiny screen instead. So I want to understand what's the technical difference.

For reference, my golang code goes like: (tiny screen)

```
cmd := exec.Command(filepath.Join(".", "Game.exe"))
err := cmd.Start()
```

Disassembling the secondary executable gives me this: (normal screen)

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
004043AF  |.  51            PUSH ECX                                 ; /pProcessInformation = 59C7F521 -> {hProcess=???,hThread=???,ProcessID=???,ThreadID=???}
004043B0  |.  52            PUSH EDX                                 ; |pStartupInfo => OFFSET LOCAL.16
004043B1  |.  68 28E54000   PUSH OFFSET 0040E528                     ; |CurrentDirectory = "."
004043B6  |.  50            PUSH EAX                                 ; |pEnvironment => NULL
004043B7  |.  50            PUSH EAX                                 ; |CreationFlags => 0
004043B8  |.  6A 01         PUSH 1                                   ; |InheritHandles = TRUE
004043BA  |.  50            PUSH EAX                                 ; |pThreadSecurity => NULL
004043BB  |.  50            PUSH EAX                                 ; |pProcessSecurity => NULL
004043BC  |.  68 10E54000   PUSH OFFSET 0040E510                     ; |CommandLine = "Game.exe"
004043C1  |.  50            PUSH EAX                                 ; |ApplicationName => NULL
004043C2  |.  FF15 8CB04000 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&KERNEL32.CreateProc ; \KERNEL32.CreateProcessA
```

When I say the game is a tiny screen it shows up like this:

[image]

versus this when it is executed directly with double click: (don't mind it being black its just the normal startup)

[image]

---

Additional info: Actually the problem only exists in windows 10. Windows 7 is completely fine.

For windows 10, the only way to make it normal screen is to use this setting:

[image]

When that is used, I get the normal screen when using double click or the secondary executable. But its still a tiny screen on my Golang app.

Comment: Beyond the programs *environment* and *current working directory* potentially being different, there should be no difference between running a program normally by typing its name in a shell or double-clicking it in some GUI environment.

Comment: Maybe you need to set the `dwXSize` and `dwYSize` members of a [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-_startupinfoa) structure?

Comment: I wonder whether it could be possible to use [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to peer into how `CreateProcess[Ex]` gets called in both the cases.

Comment: Not sure I've read the problem description correctly. In Windows 10, before applying the compatibility settings, the program behaved the same (small window) for all three methods of launching (the old 2003 launcher, the new golang launcher, and Explorer)? Is that right? Then setting compatibility changed Explorer and the old (32-bit?) launcher, but not golang?

Comment: @JaMiT exactly. But I've figured it out. Adding the compatibility setting to the golang launcher itself instead of the game fixed the issue for the launcher but its again small window in double click. Having the compatibility setting on both the launcher and the exe makes it work ok.

Comment: @majidarif Ah, so the issue seems to be that golang disregards its target's compatibility settings. It seems like you're in a position to answer your own question.

Comment: When the shim engine is initialized at process startup, it sets the current compatibility layers in the environment variable `__COMPAT_LAYER` (e.g. to the value "16BitColor"). This allows propagating the compatibility layer to child processes that inherit the parent's environment variables. You can of course manually add the `__COMPAT_LAYER` variable.

Comment: I don't know why `CreateProcessW` isn't writing this shim data in your case when it's set in the registry key "[HKLM|HKCU]\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers". In my test with a debugger and procmon, I can see it query the registry and write the data to the PEB `pShimData` in the child process. (It's kind of hacky that they implement this by having the parent process write directly to the PEB of the child. By now they should have migrated this to use a creation attribute that's passed to `NtCreateUserProcess`.)

Comment: i just opened an app in 3 diff methods and ran procdump, they all checked AppCompatFlags correctly.  Double clicking the exe, calling CreateProcess() on it in a C++ app, and using "start app.exe" on the command line.  All 3 queried AppCompatFlags.  I did not test with GoLang, you should try ProcMon on your golang app and see what happens